# In Haskell why does the GHCi cmd line allow me to change the value of a variable, which isn't allowed when loading from a text file

Tags: haskell, ghci

I can do the following in GHCi, which I understand shouldn't be possible in Haskell:

```
Prelude> myPi = 3.14
Prelude> myPi = 4
Prelude> myPi
4
```

But if I put this in a file it gives me an error

```
-- main.hs
myPi = 3.14
myPi = 4
```

```
Prelude> :l main.hs
main.hs:2:1: error:
    Multiple declarations of ‘myPi’
    Declared at: main.hs:1:1
                 main.hs:2:1
```

What is GHCi doing to allow me to 'redeclare' variables. Is there a way of stopping this happening?

Comment: In Haskell you can not change the value of a variable. All variables are immutable. You can only define another variable with the same name (and only in certain situations, like with a `let`).

Comment: That's what I thought, but the command line appears to allow me to do this. The scope of command line declarations appear to be global, i.e. you can use them after you have written them. Why can you mutate variable declarations?

Comment: no, what you did was basically write `let myPi = 3.14 in (let myPi = 4 in ...)`, so you constructed *another* variables with the same name, that is more locally scoped.

Comment: ah, ok. How would you get to the original value of `myPi`?

Comment: well you can not really exit a `let` in a `do` block, since its scope is the rest of the `do` lines. But you could for example write something like: `let myPi = 4 in myPi`, and then it will automatically "exit" the scope you defined at the end of that line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I can do the following in GHCi, which I understand shouldn't be possible in Haskell
>
> ```
> Prelude> myPi = 3.14
> Prelude> myPi = 4
> Prelude> myPi
> ```

In `ghci` you basically are working in an "implicit" `do`. And the interpreter will add an implicit `let` to it.

You thus wrote the equivalent of:

```
main = do
    let myPi = 3.14
    let myPi = 4
    print myPi
```

If we desugar the `do` notation, we thus obtain:

```
main = let myPi = 3.14 in (let myPi = 4 in print myPi)
```

What we here did was constructing *two* different variables, that happen to have the same name. `let` defines a scope, and thus in your `print myPi`, it takes the variables that has the closest scope, so the second variable.

But outside the inner `let … in …`, there is still a `myPi` variable with value `3.14`. So you did *not* change the value of `myPi`.

If we for example write:

```
main = do
    let myPi = 3.14
    let myPi = 4 in print myPi
    print myPi
```

It will first print `4` (from the inner `myPi`) and then `3.14` (from the outer `myPi`).

Comment: many thanks, I thought there might be some hidden scoping going on there somewhere

Answer (score 9):

Here's a session which demonstrates that GHCi does *not* change the value, but rather introduces a new variable with the same name:

```
Prelude> let myPi = 3.14
Prelude> let f x = x + myPi
Prelude> let myPi = 4
Prelude> f 0
3.14
```

Comment: Thanks, that a pretty neat example